Why does my flex env google app engine instance have a minimum of 2 instances running, even when there is no traffic?
I'm running a flex environment google app engine service, and I can't understand why it always shows 2 instances running, even when there is no traffic. The flex environment I'm using is a distroless golang service.
I know with flex environments you can't set min instance properties. Now that I am getting traffic, I see the instance count is at 3, which makes me wonder, are two of these instances actually doing anything.
My CPU utilization runs at about 30%. Memory usage is 1.6 GB.
My yaml:
instance_class: F1

runtime: custom
env: flex

includes:
  - .env.yaml


Do you have 2 services deployed or only 1? Is your service run stuff in background?

just the one default service

You must include a scaling description in your app.yaml file to control the min instance value.
By default, the min instance is set to 2. Set it to one in your scaling config override.

You are correct sir. I don't know why I couldn't find that, thank you.
